# How to display month name in my language

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have 2 variables for month and year. I would like to display month name in my language but i dont manage to make it working. Here is my code

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('ro.utf-8', 'ro_RO.UTF-8', 'ro_RO.utf-8', 'ro', 'ro_RO', 'ro_RO.ISO8859-2')); 

$luna=$_GET['month'];
$an=$_GET['year'];

$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $luna);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
$data='Arhiva '.$monthName.' - '.$an.'';
```

it displays June 2014 and i want Iunie 2014 June=Iunie in my country. The month given by link is dinamic and it can be any number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strftime` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('ro.utf-8', 'ro_RO.UTF-8', 'ro_RO.utf-8', 'ro', 'ro_RO', 'ro_RO.ISO8859-2')); 

$luna=$_GET['month'];
$an=$_GET['year'];

$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $luna);
$monthName = strftime('%B', $dateObj->getTimestamp());
$data='Arhiva '.$monthName.' - '.$an.'';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert with [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/intldateformatter.create.php) function

```
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $luna);

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("ro_RO",
                                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                                    'Europe/Bucharest', 
                                    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
                                    'MMMM');
        
echo $formatter->format($dateObj).' - '.$an; // Iunie - 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR'); 
$monthName  = strftime("%B",mktime(0, 0, 0, $_GET['month']));
echo  $monthName ; //It outputs month name in your local language that you have set in 'setlocale'
```

In this case it is set to French. Similarly you can use it for your locale by passing your language code like:

```
sr_BA - Serbian (Montenegro);
sr_CS - Serbian (Serbia);
sr_ME - Serbian (Serbia and Montenegro);
```

Happy coding!!